# how can i get my project to show under my repo using git when deploying?(django)

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, deployment, repo

`:~/portfolio$ ls README.md  venvxz`
My Django project isn't showing up under my repo in the terminal when i want to deploy with AWS! Ive tried "git push origin master", git remote add origin. i think last time i had it working, i pushed my project under a certain branch on GitHub.
I have tried git merge, git checkout, my project on GitHub is currently under git master. If i try git branch, it shows 'main'
I cannot deploy my website because of this.

`:~/portfolio$ git branch

- main`

Comment: To deploy you need to clone the branch and if some changes are there you need to `git pull origin master`. Why to `git push`...??

Comment: Secondly, you are currently in main branch, and doing `git push origin master`. Not clear what you want to do.

Comment: I guess if all of your code is in master, then simply you need to checkout the master branch. Do `git checkout master`

Comment: I’ll try it, thanks

Comment: i do not seem to understand, this isnt working, i tried git pull, git clone